# External table load and discard count

Tags: oracle, import

In below external table I have this issues in checking the loading and omitted count .The below record is omitted in both check and is that issue due to NOT condition?

Table data:

```
    COL1   COL2       COL3 
    Y                  SS
```

condition check to load from external table:

```
( (TRIM(COL1) = 'Y'  AND   TRIM(COL2) = 104) OR TRIM(COL1) IS NULL )
     AND   NVL(RTRIM(COL3),'X') != '9W'
```

condition check to discard record count from external table

```
NOT(( (TRIM(COL1) = 'Y'  AND   TRIM(COL2) = 104) OR TRIM(COL1) IS NULL )
     AND   NVL(RTRIM(COL3),'X') != '9W')
```

For this record with above condition it not captured in load and also in discard.

Comment: Are you using `imp` or DataPump?  Database version?  Can you post the log output?

Comment: missing of NVL check and i just got the issue .... I am using external table to load from file to table

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue missing NVL check and its working now

```
NOT(( (TRIM(COL1) = 'Y'  AND   NVL(TRIM(COL2),0) = 104) OR TRIM(COL1) IS NULL )
     AND   NVL(RTRIM(COL3),'X') != '9W')
```